# Where sku.tpl get the $sku_images in opencart

Tags: javascript, php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-3

I want to know where is the `sku.tpl` get this `$sku_images`.

[image]

I already search it using `grep` in my server but I can't find where that variable come from.

[image]

can you help me guys? I really don't know where is that variable come from.

Comment: Are you using any theme in your opencart website? And please mentioned which Opencart version are you using now?

Comment: @VipulJethva I'm using Journal theme, and my opencart version is 3.x

Comment: Default opencart does not have the sku.tpl file in his structure.

Comment: I have Journal theme, there's no sku.tpl or sku.twig in Journal theme, maybe it's belong to extension?

Answer (score 1):

use this command to find which controller is calling sky template files

`grep -r "otc/sku"`

this will list controller calling that template file,
or check vqmod / ocmod for controller code

Comment: Hmm already did, but still the same result. It's like there's no controller that call that `.tpl` but when I check in browser, there's script inside that `.tpl` that called in index.